# How to remove timer_settime in linux

Tags: c++, timer

I have some question so I ask. 
I make the project in linux about timer, but it make error.
I want to know information about remove timer.

I used the method that timer_settime and clear timer.
But It didn't remove timer.

How to remove the timer in linux? 
the timer_delete didn't work.

etc)
It is create code.

```
    sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sa.sa_sigaction = timer_callback;
    sigaddset(&sa.sa_mask, sig_no);
    if (sigaction(sig_no, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        L_ERROR("error in sigaction.");
        return;
    }

    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = sig_no;
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &sev, &timerid) == -1) {
        L_ERROR("error in timer_create.");
        return;
    }

    // Start the timer
    its.it_value.tv_sec = second;
    L_ERROR("second = %d\n", second);
    its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    its.it_interval.tv_sec = its.it_value.tv_sec;
    its.it_interval.tv_nsec = its.it_value.tv_nsec;

    if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &its, NULL) == -1) {
        L_ERROR("error in timer_settime.");
        return;
    }
```

It is delete code.

```
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
if(sigaction(sig_no, &sa, NULL) == -1)
{
          L_ERROR("[TimerDebugging] Fail to sigaction(), SIG_IGN, sig_no=%d", sig_no);
          return;
}
L_ERROR("[TimerDebugging] sigaction(), SIG_IGN, sig_no=%d", sig_no);

its.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_value.tv_nsec = 0L;
its.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
its.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;
if(timer_settime(timer_id, 0, &its, NULL) == -1)
{
          L_ERROR("[TimerDebugging] timer_settime() -for disarm timer- sig_no=%d error", sig_no);
          return;
}

result = timer_delete(timer_id);
L_ERROR("[TimerDebugging] timer_delete() result=%d", result);
if( result < 0 )
{
          L_ERROR("timer_delete() error, errno=%d", result);
          return;
}
```

we used multiple signal of timer.

Thanks any reply.

Comment: It's very likely this question will be put on hold in its current form. Can I suggest you add a short example showing what you tried, how/why it didn't work, and please explain what you are trying to achieve? Right now,  it is not possible for anyone to help.

Comment: Do you mean [`timer_delete`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_delete)? Or have you just tried to set the timer with the fields set to zero (as per [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/timer_settime))?

Comment: How do you know that `timer_delete` didn't work? Can you please show some code? How do you initialize the timer? Start it? Delete it?

Comment: In the case of error, you do not actually print `errno`. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get it as a printable string. You might want to start with that. And then check your variables (`timerid` versus `timer_id`), and their values.

Comment: where do I use strerror? with the timer_delete?? where use the code?

Comment: When you print errors, for example if there's an error with `timer_delete` you print a message saying so, but you don't print the actual error, do e.g. `L_ERROR("timer_delete() error, errno=%d (%s)", errno, strerror(errno));`

Comment: Also, for debugging purposes, print the timer-id (variable `timerid`) after you create the timer, and also print it (variable `timer_id`) before deleting it. If it's not the same you have the reason for your error. Since `timer_t` is an opaque type, you may want to do e.g. `printf("Timer id = 0x%08lx\n", (intptr_t) timerid);` (or possibly using format `"%016llx"`) That should work okay.

Comment: Does anyone know it calling ` timer_delete()` will cancel the link to the signal handler function, or does that have to be done explicitly?